# How to get QWidget from QGraphicsScene item?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgraphicswidget

I have added QTextEdit to QGraphicsScene.
How now to access the properties and methods of the widget?

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QTextEdit *te=new QTextEdit();
scene.addWidget(te);

................................

foreach(auto item,scene.items()) {

    auto te=(QTextEdit*)item;
    auto isReadOnly=te->isReadOnly(); // Error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QGraphicsScene::addWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) returns a [`QGraphicsProxyWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsproxywidget.html) which, as its name suggests, acts as a proxy to the widget added (your `QTextEdit` in this case).  So you can either save the proxy for use later...

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
auto *proxy = scene.addWidget(new QTextEdit);
```

or, when looping over items, use something like...

```
for (const auto *item: scene.items()) {
    if (const auto *proxy = dynamic_cast<const QGraphicsProxyWidget *>(item)) {
        if (const auto *te = dynamic_cast<const QTextEdit *>(proxy->widget())) {
            auto isReadOnly = te->isReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```